# How to change tint of navigation bar in SafariViewController when setting UIButton appearance in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiappearance, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to change the tint of the navigation bar in a `SFSafariViewController` when `UIButton.appearance()` is being set in the `AppDelegate`.

For example:

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Here is the global setting that I want to override in the 
       SafariViewController
    UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
}
```

**SFSafariViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This will change the toolbar tint but not the Done button or the 
       website name in the "navigation" section
    preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

However, both the Done button and the color of the website name are still green.

I also tried making overrides for objects in the App Delegate. None of them worked.

**App Delegate** (also in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`)

```
// These are attempts to override the tint set above. None seem to work.
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [SFSafariViewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [SFSafariViewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [SFSafariViewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white
```

I also attempted setting the tint of the view in the Safari View Controller itself, but it does not tint the navigation bar.

**SFSafariViewController** (also in `viewDidLoad`)

```
// This can be seen by bringing up an alert like in a peek
view.tintColor = UIColor.purple
```

This was written in **Swift 3.0** and tested in **Xcode 8.1**.

I have posted a sample project on [github](https://github.com/AmeliaBoli/SafariVCTintTester).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*(Colors were chosen for testing purposes.)*

Comment: @Adrian Note the part starting with "SFSafariViewController".

Comment: @MatthewFrederick Crawling back in my hole

Comment: @Adrian Sorry, didn't mean it negatively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way that I found is to use the same code that you have written in `AppDelegate` but at appropriate positions.

On presenting the safari controller

```
//Just before presenting the Safari Controller, change the color to red. It will make the Done button color to red.
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
let controller = StyledSafariViewController(url: appleUrl)
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in the `viewWillDisappear` method of **SafariController** class

Again make your button color to global

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    //resetting your button color
    UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Comment: I clearly mentioned that with this code I am able to change the done button Color only for this safari controller. Tested on Xcode  8.1

Comment: Cool man , as per requirement it didn't worked .That's why asked ?

Comment: If it didn't worked, then the OP might not have accepted the answer :)

Comment: At the time i posted the comment she didn't accept it . Chill out man you are code is working like a pro